# ArcGIS Pro: Counting points near a line within a sliding window

Tags: arcgis-pro, line

I am trying to determine a solution to this problem in ArcGIS Pro:

We need to generate a count of points that lie within a specified distance of a line, evaluated within all contiguous 1 mile sections of that line.

Is there a tool that would take a line feature class and split it into sections along a sliding distance window?  Ideally, we would end up with a line feature class with many 1 mile sections of line that have their center point offset by some distance (say 100 ft).  We could then use the summarize near tool on that layer to get a count of nearby points.  I'm just not sure how to do the first step!

Does anyone have any pointers for this problem?

Comment: I'd compute chainage of each point and compute count for sliding interval.

Comment: Just to be clear...  Are you simply asking how to split a line into segments of equal length (1 mile)?  If you're OK with using Python and arcpy, the `Geometry` class has a `.segmentAlongLine()` function that can be used for this purpose.  You can use this within a loop inside an `InsertCursor` to create multiple line segment features and intervals along the line.  Having said all that, @FelixIP suggestion completely avoids the need to split the line into segments at all.

Comment: @FelixIP, could you expand a little on how to compute the count on a sliding interval based on a chainage value?  Is there a built in tool for that, or would we need to use python?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this structure of input data:

[image]

This script:

```
import pandas as pd
## get inputs
streetsDict = {s:shp for s,shp in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("LONG_RIVERS",("SOURCE","Shape@"))}
chainages = pd.DataFrame(arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("CHAINAGE" ,("SOURCE","D_ALONG")))
# dataframe to store results
newRow = 0
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns=["SOURCE","FROM","TO","COUNT","X","Y"])
## shuffle through lines
for s in streetsDict:
    xtrct = chainages[chainages.SOURCE==s]
    street = streetsDict[s]
    maxL = street.length
    FROM = 0
## loop until end of line
    while True:
        TO = min(FROM + 1000,maxL)
        midPoint = street.positionAlongLine((FROM+TO)/2).firstPoint
        df = xtrct[(xtrct.D_ALONG > FROM) & (xtrct.D_ALONG < TO)]
        DF.loc[newRow]=[s,FROM,TO,len(df),midPoint.X,midPoint.Y]
        newRow+=1
        if TO>=maxL:break
        FROM+=100
    print (maxL)
DF.to_csv ("maxqh.csv", index = None, header=True)
```

will produce something like:

[image]

saved in csv file in a folder of your project